# how to fetch data from parse database and use it in different function

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm new to android studio and in learning phase.
I'm able to get current user location and store it in Parse server. Now i have also stored the Geo location of some super markets in Parse database in a class "Hospitals". Now i'm trying to retrieve the Geo location of specific hospital and trying to compare the distance between current user and the hospital.

When i'm trying to fetch the value from Parse database, it is calculated in background, so i'm unable to use it in different function to get the difference in distance as the return value will be null.

Below code is used:

```
 class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

   ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

     private Context context;

List<ParseUser> object = new ArrayList<>();
final ParseGeoPoint[] parlourUser = new ParseGeoPoint[1];

RemoteDataTask(Context context) {
    Log.i("info", "Enetred RemoteDataTask");
    this.context = context;
}      

  @Override protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    Log.i("info", "Entered doInbackground");

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    try{

        Log.i("info", "value is " + query.get("aifg14PNKz"));


        object.set(1, query.get("aifg14PNKz"));

        Log.i("info", "Object value" + object.get(1));

        parlourUser[0] = object.get(0).getParseGeoPoint("Location");
        Log.i("info", "Location of parlour user " + parlourUser[0]);


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is a very wrong practice to make a function which depends on the background thread.

**query.getInBackground**

It will work on the background thread and

After Background Query completed, this callback method communicates with UI thread

```
new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
}
```

Your function will not work if **query.getInBackground** take some time.

Solution to your problem in 2 steps

**1) You can call this in AsyncTask and handle the Query in background**

```
 // RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private  Context context;
        List<ParseObject> object;
        final ParseGeoPoint[] hospitalUser = new ParseGeoPoint[1];

        RemoteDataTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Title...");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


            // Create the array
            try {

                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Lakme");
                object = query.find();

                if (ob != null) {
                    hospitalUser[0] = object.getParseGeoPoint("Location");

                    //calculate distance
                }


            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
           // You can use "hospitalUser" Object here.

        }
    }
```

Call it from where you call this method

```
new RemoteDataTask(YourActivity.this).execute();
```

2) Calculate Distance once got a result from query

- if it does not involve UI thread then you can calculate it in
  "doInBackground" or
- if it does involve UI thread you should use it in "onPostExecute" or
- if you want to get notified after AsyncTask completed then you can
  implement interface like this.

Comment: Also, I have one more query. If i want to query the User class from Parse database, will the above code work? I'm getting error when used the same code for User class, but its working fine for other class. I want to fetch the Location Geo point from User class but not for current user. I want to fetch Location based on value from different column in User class.   Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please share error message? it will be helpful.

Comment: I have edited my question with new code (since its too long to add in comments) , can you please check and let me know where i'm going wrong? I'm trying to fetch geolocation from User class and put it in List, later i can use this array list to display in list View.

Comment: checked your code. Find  "object.get(0).getParseGeoPoint" You may be passing the wrong position. It should be 1 instead of 0. object.get(1).getParseGeoPoint

Comment: Oh, that was a typo i guess. but i tried with 1 also, no luck. Anyways, i have found a different way to do it and able to get the results. Thanks a lot for your time and help